# Mysql in sentence

Tags: mysql

Maybe I didnt explain well.

these are the tables:

**Table 1**

```
CREATE TABLE `notforeverdata` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`num` varchar(255) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `notforeverdata` VALUES (1, '4,3,0,5');
```

**Table 2**

```
CREATE TABLE `notforeverdata2` (
`id2` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`num2` varchar(255) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `notforeverdata2` VALUES (1, '2,5,6,8');
```

What I need to do is to check is if any of the numbers of the column "num" in notforeverdata exists in the column num2 of notforeverdata2. in this case the number "5" in the col num of notforeverdata exists in notforeverdata2.

Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: There's the [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function, maybe it can help you

Answer (score 0):

For this example I will create a table, load it with random numbers, and search for each number in a provided list. Here is the catch: the provided list must start with and end with a comma.

From your question, I will use ',3,2,5,'

Here is the example

```
use test
drop table if exists notforeverdata;
create table notforeverdata
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    num VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
insert into notforeverdata (num) values
(2),(7),(9),(11),(13),(15),(4),(3),(90),(97),(18),(5),(17);
SELECT * FROM notforeverdata;
SELECT * FROM notforeverdata WHERE LOCATE(CONCAT(',',num,','),(',3,2,5,'));
```

I actually ran it in MySQl 5.5.12 on my desktop. Here is the result:

```
mysql> use test
drop table if exists notforeverdata;
Database changed
mysql> drop table if exists notforeverdata;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> create table notforeverdata
    -> (
    ->     id int not null auto_increment,
    ->     num VARCHAR(255),
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> insert into notforeverdata (num) values
    -> (2),(7),(9),(11),(13),(15),(4),(3),(90),(97),(18),(5),(17);
Query OK, 13 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 13  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM notforeverdata;
+----+------+
| id | num  |
+----+------+
|  1 | 2    |
|  2 | 7    |
|  3 | 9    |
|  4 | 11   |
|  5 | 13   |
|  6 | 15   |
|  7 | 4    |
|  8 | 3    |
|  9 | 90   |
| 10 | 97   |
| 11 | 18   |
| 12 | 5    |
| 13 | 17   |
+----+------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM notforeverdata WHERE LOCATE(CONCAT(',',num,','),(',3,2,5,'));
+----+------+
| id | num  |
+----+------+
|  1 | 2    |
|  8 | 3    |
| 12 | 5    |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

This will, of course, perform a full table scan. Notwithstanding, this works.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer I edited the question to be more clear.